# Show several bookmark on the map

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I'm using the example of graphhopper android using openstreemaps.
I have this code to show marker on the map:

```
  void loadMap(File areaFolder) {
    logUser("Cargando mapa");

    // Map events receiver
    mapView.map().layers().add(new MapEventsReceiver(mapView.map()));
    // Map file source
    MapFileTileSource tileSource = new MapFileTileSource();
    tileSource.setMapFile(new File(areaFolder, currentArea + ".map").getAbsolutePath());
    VectorTileLayer l = mapView.map().setBaseMap(tileSource);
    mapView.map().setTheme(VtmThemes.DEFAULT);
    mapView.map().layers().add(new BuildingLayer(mapView.map(), l));
    mapView.map().layers().add(new LabelLayer(mapView.map(), l));

    // Markers layer
    itemizedLayer = new ItemizedLayer<>(mapView.map(), (MarkerSymbol) null);
    mapView.map().layers().add(itemizedLayer);

    // Map position
    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.getBoolean("esUnArray")) {

            final ArrayList<PosicionGeografica> array = new ArrayList<>();
            // array.add(new PosicionGeografica("Santiago de Cuba", 20.0208302, -75.8266678));
            array.add(new PosicionGeografica("Fomento", 22.1039, -79.7217));

            for (PosicionGeografica object : array) {

                rlatitud = object.getLatitud();
                rlongitud = object.getLongitud();

                itemizedLayer.removeAllItems();
                mapView.map().setMapPosition(rlatitud, rlongitud, 1 << 20);

                GeoPoint enti = new GeoPoint(rlatitud, rlongitud);
                itemizedLayer.addItem(createMarkerItem(enti, R.drawable.marker_icon_green));
                mapView.map().updateMap(true);
            }

        } else {

            itemizedLayer.removeAllItems();
            mapView.map().setMapPosition(rlatitud, rlongitud, 1 << 20);

            GeoPoint enti = new GeoPoint(rlatitud, rlongitud);
            itemizedLayer.addItem(createMarkerItem(enti, R.drawable.marker_icon_green));
            mapView.map().updateMap(true);
        }

    } else {
        mapView.map().setMapPosition(23.135039, -82.359495, 1 << 16);
        mapView.map().updateMap(true);

    }

    setContentView(mapView);
    //loadGraphStorage();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private MarkerItem createMarkerItem(GeoPoint p, int resource) {
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resource);
    Bitmap bitmap = AndroidGraphics.drawableToBitmap(drawable);
    MarkerSymbol markerSymbol = new MarkerSymbol(bitmap, 1.5f, 1);
    MarkerItem markerItem = new MarkerItem("", "", p);
    markerItem.setMarker(markerSymbol);
    return markerItem;
}
```

When what comes in the inten.extras is a single geographical position is displayed correctly. But when an array of geographic positions comes, only the marker of the last element of the array is shown. Help!

Comment: where do you create your bookmarks?

Comment: `itemizedLayer.removeAllItems();` occurs in your loop before each `addItem(...)` call; doesn't that mean you're deleting all your items before adding each one?

Comment: Thank you very much, I had not realized that detail

Comment: And how could you establish a minimum zoom so that when you put the small pay with your fingers you stop at a certain size and can not continue decreasing it?